# Generating a 10MHz modulated signal

Tags: modulation, frequency-synthesis

For an application I need to generate a 10 MHz sine wave signal that is modulated with 20 KHz triangle signal. This is going to be frequency modulated.

This goes into another circuit which require a low phase noise. What is my best option to generate this signal effectively with low noise and reasonable cost. So far I have seen DSS solutions from ADI.

Comment: @ThePhoton frequency

Comment: 20 kHz is the modulation frequency, or the peak deviation?

Comment: @ThePhoton  20khz is the frequency of the triangle signal that needs to be modulating the 10MHz signal.

Comment: Modulating the 10 MHz by how much? What is the frequency deviation required?

Comment: This is hard work. Like watching paint dry!

Comment: @Andyaka asking good questions also require knowledge. But hey that’s why we are here. To learn

Comment: @ThePhoton I don’t understand this comment. My mental model is that we are trying to mix 20kHz triangle signal to a 10MHz carrier wave.

Comment: You are modulating the frequency with a 20 kHz triangle wave. You could be modulating it between 9.99 MHz and 10.01 MHz, or between 2 MHz and 18 MHz. Some solutions might work for one but not the other. (Another word for this is *modulation index*).

Comment: @ThePhoton I get it. This is for FMCW application of radar and it requires 10MHz ref signal. My objective is to modulate this reference to generate the FMCW signal. I need to check the data sheet to see.

Comment: 10 MHz seems like an inconveniently low frequency (in terms of required antenna size) to do that kind of thing at. And unless you live in Somalia or someplace, a band that's likely to be cluttered with lots of licensed users who might notice your experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions that come to mind:

- **Microcontroller + DAC**: The use of DSP / DDS (direct digital synthesis) techniques on a fast microcontroller (preferably with an integrated FPU) to generate a frequency modulated sine wave could be a viable/inexpensive solution, with an internal or external (parallel) DAC, and an accurate external clock source. - A 10 MHz (carrier) and a 20 kHz modulation signal could probably be generated with a microcontroller from the STM32F/H series (by ST). - Lookup tables, [ARM DSP optimizations](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/DSP/html/index.html) and fix point math could help. - Whether the result satisfies your application's requirements depends on the necessary quality of the signal (sampling rate/depth, aliasing effects, jitter etc.). - The signal quality could probably be improved with an external analog filter.
- **FPGA + DAC**: The signal could be generated with an FPGA and digital-to-analog converted with a fast parallel DAC, all clocked from an accurate clock source. The sine wave/carrier and the modulation signal (triangle) can be generated right inside the FPGA. (Instead of using a lookup table, the [CORDIC](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279635) way of implementing a sine function could come in handy). This could probably already be accomplished with a small/inexpensive FPGA from the ICE40 series (by Lattice).
- **Specialized IC**: The direct digital synthesis (DDS) chips by Analog Devices might be a good choice, like you've mentioned above (?). (But I've never worked with them myself yet, so I can't tell...) - Compared to the other solutions above, specialized ICs are black boxes, and your solution will strongly depend on the supply of a single manufacturer.
- **Analog cirucit**: The whole thing could be done with analog techniques, but that's usually harder, in my experience. And it is probably more expensive/difficult to get reliable/stable results.